# Can someone explaine how #ifeq ../section key works using handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, operators, keystonejs

I am currently using Handlebar.js for my website and I have the following code in one of my views:

```
{{# each navLinks}}
  {{#ifeq ../section key}}
    {{key}}
  {{else}}
  {{/ifeq}}
{{/each}}
```

And then in my middleware I have:

```
locals.navLinks = [
  { label: 'Projects', key: 'projects', href: '/projects' },
  { label: 'Journey', key: 'journey', href: '/journey' },
  { label: 'Social media', key: 'social', href: '/social' },
  { label: 'Reach me', key: 'contact', href: '/contact' }
];
```

And then there is a helper function:

```
// standard hbs equality check, pass in two values from template
// {{#ifeq keyToCheck data.myKey}} [requires an else blockin template regardless]
_helpers.ifeq = function(a, b, options) {
    if (a == b) {
        return options.fn(this);
    } else {
        return options.inverse(this);
    }
};
```

I understand that the `{{# each navLinks}}` means that it goes through the array of `locals.navlinks`.

But how does the `{{#ifeq ../section key}}` works? I do not see any reference to any of the object keys inside the array or keys called ../section, nor any reference to `eq` after the `{{#if`?

Also what is the purpose of the `#` in the `{{# each navLinks}}` and in the `{{#ifeq ../section key}}`?

Lastly my end goal would be to write something in my view using handlebar like:

```
if ( navlinks.key === 'projects' ) {
  class="A"
} else {
  class="B"
}
```

Any explanation would be great.

Thank you for your help.

Jules

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. The reason there is a ../content is because each view has its own module. In this case there is `locals.section = 'nameOfView';

Because it was in an `{{# each...` block the only way to retrieve the `content` data from within is to go to its parent using `../`.

So in order for me to do a simple check on the page this was the script I used:

```
{{#ifeq section "journey"}}it'sTrue{{else}}it'sFalse{{/ifeq}}
```

And thats it. The only thing I have not quite figured out yet is the `#` part.

Comment: Please mark your question as answered (with your own answer)., Also: Blocks are represented in Handlebars with the pound (#) symbol followed by an expression. Blocks end with a closing mustache, {{/expression}}.